# How to load metadata directly from chromecast receiver?

Tags: chromecast

I tried sending metadata from the sender to the receiver using the following code which is working fine.

```
const mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(url, type);
/* --------------------------------------------- */
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
mediaInfo.metadata.metadataType = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.GENERIC;
mediaInfo.metadata.title = title;
/* --------------------------------------------- */
const request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
```

But now I am trying to make an api call inside the receiver itself and trying to load metadata directly right from the receiver itself.

Is there a way to do that?
If so how to do that? I went through so many pages of chromecast receiver setup and couldn't find a way to do that.

Your help is largely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setMessageInterceptor` on load and call the api and set the data on metaData and add to `loadRequestData`

last return the `loadRequestData`

```
        const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
        const MediaMetadata = new cast.framework.messages.MediaMetadata()
        const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

    /* --------------------------------------------- */

        playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
            cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, loadRequestData => {
                return fetch('thirdpartyapi')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {

                            MediaMetadata.title = 'your.Title'
                            MediaMetadata.subtitle = 'your.Subtitle'
                       /* --------------------------------------------- */
                           loadRequestData.media.metadata = MediaMetadata
                       /* --------------------------------------------- */
                           return loadRequestData;

                    })
            });
```